# Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103026600 payfort

Tags: ios, swift, payfort

I am using `PayFort IOS SDK` in my project by following their document found here: https://docs.payfort.com/pdf/FORT_Mobile-SDK_iOS_Integration_Guide_v_2.8.pdf

reached step 4 in 5.3 ... and I am getting this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField setFloatingLabelActiveTextColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103026600'

and my code is:

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let payFort = PayFortController.init(enviroment: KPayFortEnviromentSandBox)

    let request = NSMutableDictionary.init()
    request.setValue("1000", forKey: "amount")
    request.setValue("AUTHORIZATION", forKey: "command")
    request.setValue("USD", forKey: "currency")
    request.setValue("email@domain.com", forKey: "customer_email")
    request.setValue("en", forKey: "language")
    request.setValue("112233682686", forKey: "merchant_reference")
    request.setValue("token" , forKey: "sdk_token")

    payFort?.callPayFort(withRequest: request, currentViewController: self,
                        success: { (requestDic, responeDic) in
                            print("success")
    }, canceled: { (requestDic, responeDic) in
        print("canceled")
    },
       faild: { (requestDic, responeDic, message) in
        print("faild")
    })

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: this error is with your UITextField not from library I think

Comment: @PPL i don't have any textfield

Comment: https://github.com/bhoopend232/PayfortDemo

Comment: https://github.com/ThabreshVivid/PayfortPayment

Comment: https://github.com/junaid04/PayFortExample

Comment: @AbuUlHassan were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and from the comments, I found the solution it was due to UITextField poor implementation, payfort sdk wasn't that files previously. Now, I created a sample project, You can get the project from [here](https://github.com/naveedahmad99/PayfortPaymentDemo-iOS)

https://github.com/naveedahmad99/PayfortPaymentDemo-iOS

Video Demo: https://github.com/naveedahmad99/PayfortPaymentDemo-iOS/blob/master/Screenshot/demo_shot.gif

[image]

Comment: I can't see this window within your app.

Comment: @Newsonic check payfort customisation files, you will get these ui changes.

Comment: Yeah I had to change some configuration and enable the mobile SDK in the account. Thanks.